Flutter searching a listview
The following code should search a listview for a wilcard and display the results.
I can see that the function _runFilter is running as expected from test code "print("line 63: _runFilter ran");"
I can also confirm the function find the correct list of filtered results from these two lines: print("line 73 filtered: ");
print(_foundItems);
However the displayed listview is not updating, and I confirmed that using this testcode (it is not outputted):
print("line 119: filtered items before listview builder:");
print(_foundItems);
Please could you help me understand why the listview builder is not refreshing?
class ItemList extends StatelessWidget {
  ItemList({Key? key}) : super(key: key) {
    _stream = _reference.snapshots();
    _foundItems = items; // Initialize _foundItems with items
  }

  final Query _reference = FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('collection_name').orderBy(
      "dlastupd", descending: true);
  late final Stream<QuerySnapshot> _stream;
  late List<Map<dynamic, dynamic>> _foundItems;
  final List<Map<dynamic, dynamic>> items = [];

  void _runFilter(String enteredKeyword) {
    print("line 63: _runFilter ran");
    if (enteredKeyword.isEmpty) {
      // if the search field is empty or only contains white space
      _foundItems = items;
      print("line 67 unfiltered");
    } else {
      _foundItems = items
          .where((item) =>
          item["name"].toLowerCase().contains(enteredKeyword.toLowerCase()))
          .toList();
    }
    print("line 73 filtered: ");
    print(_foundItems);
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('Updates'),
      ),
      body: Column(
        children: [
          Padding(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.all(18.0),
            child: TextField(
              onChanged: (value) => _runFilter(value),
              decoration: InputDecoration(
                  labelText: 'Search', suffixIcon: Icon(Icons.search)),
            ),
          ),
          const SizedBox(
            height: 20,
          ),
          Expanded(
            child: StreamBuilder<QuerySnapshot>(
              stream: _stream,
              builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot snapshot) {
                if (snapshot.hasError) {
                  return Center(child: Text('Some error occurred ${snapshot.error}'));
                }
                if (snapshot.hasData) {
                  QuerySnapshot querySnapshot = snapshot.data;
                  List<QueryDocumentSnapshot> documents = querySnapshot.docs;
                  items.clear(); // Clear items to avoid duplication
                  items.addAll(documents.map((e) =>
                  {
                    'name': e['name'],
                    'country': e['country'],
                    'dlastupd': e['dlastupd'],
                    'dlastupd date': DateTime.fromMillisecondsSinceEpoch(
                        e['dlastupd'] * 1000),
                    'id': e['id'],
                    'type': e['type'],
                  }));
                  _runFilter(""); // Filter items initially with an empty string
                  print("line 119: filtered items before listview builder:");
                  print(_foundItems);
                  return ListView.builder(
                      itemCount: _foundItems.length,
                      itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
                        Map thisItem = _foundItems[index];
                        return ListTile(
                          title: Text.rich(
                              TextSpan(
                                  children: [
                                    TextSpan(text: formatDate(thisItem['dlastupd date'], [d, '', M]) + " " + thisItem['country'] + " (" + thisItem['type'][0] + thisItem['type'][1] + ") - " + thisItem['name'] + " " ,
                                        style: TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.normal)),
                                  ]
                              )
                          ),
                          onTap: () {
                            Navigator.pushNamed(
                              context,
                              '/factfile',
                              arguments: {
                                'id': thisItem['id'],
                              },
                            );
                          },
                        );
                      });
                }
                return Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator());
              },
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}


Try to add a key property (make sure that you set new key when new data comes) to a ListView widget to make sure that the widget will be rebuild

Thank you @MaciejSzakacz I will research that. Am I ok to have ItemList as a stateless widget or should it be stateful?

also should _runFilter include setState?
